# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory при использовании NanoVgDotNet CreateGL()

Tags: c#, glfw, opentk

Использую NanoVgDotNet вместе с glfw. При вызове ф-ции GlNanoVg.CreateGL() выдаёт ошибку:

```
   at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CreateProgram()
   at NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.GlNanoVg.CreateShader(NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.GlNvgShader ByRef, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
   at NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.GlNanoVg.RenderCreate(System.Object)
   at NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.NanoVg.CreateInternal(NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.NvgParams ByRef, NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.NvgContext ByRef)
   at NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.GlNanoVg.CreateGl(NanoVGDotNet.NanoVG.NvgCreateFlags)
```

Как я понял ошибка скорее в OpenTK. Но идей как её решить нету

Comment: Возможно стоит задать этот вопрос разработчику NanoVgDotNet, хотя он уже 8 лет назад забросил эту библиотеку. Возможно она уже несовместима с актуальными версиями дотнетов. Поищите что-нибудь посвежее.

Comment: я не знаю что использовать, ни одна библиотека не работает с glfw на C#. Уже второй день пытаюсь что-то сделать. Хотел сам gui написать но даже не смог подключить SharpFont для рендеринга текста, ошибка с dll

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать то?

Comment: https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl

Comment: Я находил уже SharpGL но мне бы не хотелось переделывать работающий Glfw код. Или есть способ использовать и то и другое ?

Comment: Известных мне способов нет. Так как GLFW - нативная библиотека, можете попробовать подключить ее методы через `DllImport` и работать напрямую как в C++. Нужно только приложение собирать как явный x64 или x86, в зависимости от разрядности библиотеки, но не Any CPU. Ну или копаться в исходниках того же NanoVGDotNet и разбираться, как там сделано. Но я не понимаю, зачем вам это, когда есть готовая обертка для .NET - SharpGL. Да и вообще, зачем OpenGL? Вы кроссплатформу делаете?

Comment: Я делаю 3Д движок. OpenGL первое что пришло в голову т.к. DirectX кажется слишком сложным(Просто лень учить). И я уже почти переписал весь код на SharpGL.